# SQL Server 2005 to MySQL connection

Tags: mysql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I want to be able to email a report daily from a glpi database in MySQL.  I would like to create a SSIS job to pull data from MySQL.  How do I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest using [ODBC](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-odbc.html) or the MySQL [.NET adapter](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/5.2.html).  SSIS can easily use these connections

Answer (score 1):

Create a Linked Server to mySQL from SQL Server 2005.

Comment: This is what I would do. Install the MySQL ODBC Driver on your SQL Server platform and then you can reference your MySQL database from withing SQL Server